# face book like box not showing for the logout users

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have configured the facebook like box.change the age permission  to 13
+ though after logout its not showing the page.when I am login in facebook then only I am able to see the page

Comment: Any other restrictions on the page you are trying to like?

Answer (score 0):

If your Page has any age or country restrictions, you won't be able to see it when you're logged out of your account.

To see a Page when you're logged out of Facebook, remove all age and country restrictions:

1. Log into your account and go to your Page
2. From the top of the Page, click Edit Page
3. Select Manage Permissions
4. Make sure nothing is entered in the Country Restrictions section and select Anyone (13+) for Age Restrictions
5. Click Save Changes